# How to transform List<XObject> to List<XObjectWrapper>?

Tags: java, java-8

```
public class XObject {
...
}

public class XObjectWrapper
{
  private final XObject xo;

  public XObjectWrapper(XObject xo) {
    this.xo = xo;
  }
//delegated methods
...
}
```

I have `List<XObject>`, I want to get `List<XObjectWrapper>`.

Obviously, I can do something like this:

```
List<XObjectWrapper> wrappedList = new ArrayList<XObjectWrapper> ();
for(XObject xo : xoList) 
{
  wrappedList.add(new XObjectWrapper(xo));
}
```

Can I use some new java8 feature, and do it with a single line?

Comment: Is there any parent child relationship between them ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do:

```
List<XObjectWrapper> wrappedList = 
   xoList.stream().map(XObjectWrapper::new).collect(toList());
```

(Assuming `import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;`)

### Update

For completeness, and due to possible errors in your code, here is a self-contained example:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

static class XObjectWrapper {XObjectWrapper(Object o) {}}
static class XObject {}

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Object> xoList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<XObjectWrapper> wrappedList =
        xoList.stream().map(XObjectWrapper::new).collect(toList());
    System.out.println(wrappedList);
  }
}
```